# Como adicionar uma quebra de linha depois de uma certa quantidade de caracteres?

Tags: jquery

Tenho uma variavel que recebe um texto, eu gostaria de inserir uma quebra de linha nesse texto após o caractere numero 40 em jQuery.

Essa linha especialmente:

```
$(".chat").append('<li class="other"><div class="msg"><span>' + client + ':</span><p>' + msg + '</p><time>' + time.getHours() + ':' + time.getMinutes() + '</time></div></li>');
```

A variavel `msg` precisaria receber uma quebra de linha após o caractere 40 pra caber dentro da `div` horizontalmente, verticalmente a `div` pode crescer o tanto que for, horizontalmente não, deve manter 200px ou menos.

DIV:

```
.msg {
    background: white;
    min-width: 50px;
    max-width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}
```

Comment: Tem como colocar o código que você tem no momento?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está fazendo isso da maneira errada.Pois tem que definir essa "regra" na div.

Coloquei seu problema como exemplo nesse [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mv877ant/1/)

use a propriedade do css `word-wrap: break-word`

**Como aplicar esse css no seu código ?**

Nessa linha coloque a classe do paragrafo

```
$(".chat").append('<li class="other"><div class="msg"><span>' + client + ':</span><p class="meuP">' + msg + '</p><time>' + time.getHours() + ':' + time.getMinutes() + '</time></div></li>');
```

(basicamente substituir isso `<p>` por isso `<p class="meuP">`

Defina a classe "meuP" com a propriedade que falei do CSS:

```
.meuP {      
  word-wrap: break-word;      
}
```

Comment: Funcionou corretamente. Vlw Julio!

Answer (score 1):

Ficou assim, desse modo você consegue adicionar o que você quiser a cada 40, e também pode personalizar esse número de acordo com a sua necessidade.

Lembrando que a melhor solução não é essa, o correto é via CSS, porém não é o foco principal da pergunta. O Julio respondeu, caso esteja correto é a melhor maneira.

```js
var msg = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut enim nulla, feugiat at nisi at, consectetur efficitur eros. Suspendisse tincidunt luctus ante, quis bibendum erat vulputate sit amet. Nunc metus sapien, porttitor sed luctus eget, pulvinar vitae dolor. Pellentesque sagittis bibendum tortor a laoreet. In tristique orci et eros tempus, et commodo metus scelerisque. Aliquam mollis metus ac lacinia dictum. Maecenas elementum venenatis lectus, ac tincidunt neque dapibus non. Sed finibus suscipit nisi, quis rhoncus sem ullamcorper in. Curabitur bibendum leo lacus, sed condimentum eros maximus interdum. Nulla congue consectetur feugiat. Aliquam ac feugiat nunc. Vivamus laoreet dictum leo. Fusce dictum laoreet erat, non ultrices tortor feugiat id. Maecenas vitae sem mollis, venenatis dui non, tincidunt lacus. Maecenas dictum purus.';


var i =0;
var numOfCharacters = 40;
var msgArray = msg.split(''); //Transforma em array
msg = '';
for(i = 0; i < msgArray.length; i++){ //Percorre array
    msg += msgArray[i];//Reescreve a string
    if((i+1)%numOfCharacters == 0){ //Se for divisivél por 40 insere  quebra de linha
      msg += '<br>';
    };
};
$("#message").append(msg);//Insere no HTML
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="message">

</div>
```